# UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uidocumentinteraction

I have this code that is called from within a UIAlertController:

```
func createSomeFile() {

    var output = (some NSData to output to file)


    let fileName = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.ext")
    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)

    var dataToWrite = output.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    dataToWrite?.writeToFile(url.absoluteString!, atomically: true)

    documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: url)
    documentController.UTI = "com.someUTI"
    documentController.delegate = self

    documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self, animated: true)
}
```

The last line throws an error in Xcode: "Cannot invoke 'presentOpenInMenuFromRect' with an argument list of type..."

documentController is declared as a class variable
`var documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController()`

Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign `self` to an argument which should be `UIView` (unless `self` is a subclass of `UIView`, but apparently it is not)

So try this instead:

```
documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem; that fixed the Xcode error.